# why do some angular examples have single handlebars and some have double handlebars?

Tags: angularjs, handlebars.js

Please note Double `{{ }}` :

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngMouseleave

Please note single Single: `{ }`

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Does it have something to do with "in the quotes" or "in the tag?" Please confirm. And does any one know why?

Of course the vast level of info on the [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com) site does not help:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double braces are for one-way binding a model to the template, essentially stick the value of the model into that location.

The single braces signify what type of value the attribute expects. For example:

```
<select
       ng-model="{string}"
       [name="{string}"]
       [required]
       [ng-required="{string}"]
       [ng-options="{comprehension_expression}"]>
</select>
```

- ng-model expects a string
- name (optional) expects a string
- required (optional) expects no value
- ng-required (optional) expects a string
- ng-options (optional) expects an Angular comprehension expression

The string values can be Angular [expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Versus this, which is just a direct binding:

```
<body>
    <button ng-mouseleave="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
      Increment (when mouse leaves)
    </button>
    count: {{count}}
</body>
```

Where the value `count` on the `scope` replaces `{{count}}`

Answer (score 1):

Both ways you provide a expression which are like javascript expressions.

HTML attributes that have been extended by angularjs and take an expression can take any expression without using interpolation symbol `{{}}`. Single `{}` is just to signify what should be provided.

Everywhere else you use interpolation `{{}}`

See documentation on expressions here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: AH!  I feel silly.  I would argue they could have made different choices, But I am pretty fond of that team at theGOOGs . .